# Maven release plugin with git repository ignores scm.user scm.password

Tags: git, maven, plugins, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to run a maven release build from Jenkins using [M2 Release Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/M2+Release+Plugin) with git.

Jenkins has read-only access to the git repository, so I need to specify credentials manually during the build. They are passed to the maven release plugin via `-Dusername=\*\*\*\* -Dpassword=\*\*\*\*`, which creates `scm.username` and `scm.password` in `release.properties` when I run `release:prepare` and `release:perform` manually and in order.

However, these seem to be ignored by the `release:perform` task.

Is there any other way to get the maven release plugin to accept credentials in the build?

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting [MRELEASE-832](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-832), which is regression since 2.4. So you have to wait for the next release or fall back to 2.3.2

Comment: If I am not mistaken the described behavior also occurs in earlier versions of the maven release plugin. I have given up (I am using a workaround right now), so I don't know if I will ever check it again.